# authentication popups spam when getting images from neightboor site

Tags: 2010, access-rights

I am on Sharepoint 2010 and have 2 websites, intranet (A) and mysite (B) hosted on the same Sharepoint server.

On A, I have a webpart that shows user profile images that are on B by linking them.

The Sharepoint server is on domain 1, and I have new users from domain 2.
Domain 2's Active Directory was configured to be integrated in the new domain and user profiles got imported on Sharepoint successfuly.

But problem is : when this users go to the page containing the picture, they get an authentication popup for every image on the page.
If you cancel the popups, then some images don't load.
If you full them all then no problem, but if you refresh or go to next result page with more pictures it starts again.

Infos :
This doesn't happen with the users from domain 1.
Users from 2 have been added on site B as "readers" for the target library.
The problem seems to disapear after having logged-in on B with the user account.

Anybody has an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: In terms of 'integrated' I assume this means there might be a one-way trust relationship for Domain 1 to trust Domain 2? Am I right in thinking that the image is the one that is associated in AD? I know the User Profile Service Application isn't responsible for storing these images, it more just references them to the location in AD somehow.

Comment: @pigeon the active directories have a two-ways trust relationship (forests added on each server with "allow users from this forest to log on domain" and inversely). The images are the ones associated in AD, but imported by Sharepoint so it's realy just a link on site A to : "B/Style Libraries/User Profile Pictures/someone.jpg". The problem is only that site B sends an authentication request when loading the images and logged-in user is from domain 2, till the user hasn't log-in manualy on site B

Comment: Also note : "reading" is enough to get the images, users from domain 1 also have only reading. I just can't find any difference between users from domain 1 and 2, but still they are handled a different way so I must have missed something but I don't know where to look..